logind.conf problem
I am currently running Ubuntu 24.04.1 kenrel 6.8.0-44 on a Dell Precision 7560 laptop with an Intel 11950H CPU. I’ve experienced the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04, where setting HandleLidSwitch=poweroff or HandleLidSwitch=hibernate in logind.conf causes the screen to turn off, but the power indicator light remains on, and the laptop becomes unresponsive. It does not react to any inputs, and I have to perform a hard reset by holding the power button for several seconds.
The kernel version that mostly works is 5.19.17, but it can also freeze sometimes.
Is there a known solution or an alternative configuration to safely shut down or hibernate the laptop upon closing the lid?
Update
I installed acpid. After that, I enabled the service with  systemctl enable acpid and started it with  systemctl start acpid.
Next, I created a file in /etc/acpi/events/ named lid and added the following content: event=button/lid and action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh.
I then created a script in /etc/acpi/lid.sh with the following content:
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
systemctl poweroff
In the file /etc/systemd/logind.conf, I added or modified the lines to look like this: HandleLidSwitch=ignore
In the script lid.sh, while the command systemctl poweroff works correctly, /sbin/shutdown now, hangs the system. This issue also occurs when I set HandleLidSwitch=poweroff.
